# Change pinch-zoom sensitivity in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, touch, fabricjs

I have a custom built `fabric.js` bundle with touch support. Now I can scale any object with the pinch-zoom gesture. The problem is the zoom is really really sensitive, I barely move my fingers and the object is hugely scaled.

I couldn't find much information in the documents about how I can change the sensitivity. I know `Event.js` is used to handle the touch events within `fabric.js`. Is there any way I can change this sensitivity?

Comment: How did you enable pinch zoom in the fabric could you please explain or could you please share your code ... I was developing application

Comment: @Vicky Smart I ended up using `hammer.js` to detect the gestures on the element and apply scaling manually.

Comment: Andres I have tried with hammerjs and quojs but did not get any idea could you please give me the example code  ? So i can get idea and make things work

Comment: @VickySmart see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ended up implementing touch controls myself, this is the code I made. This code was placed on the `added` event of my custom `fabric.js` object.

```
////////////////////////////// Touch event handlers
// Add listener event for pinch-zoom
var bbScope = this;
var hammer = new Hammer.Manager(this.canvas.upperCanvasEl);
var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
hammer.add([pinch]);

hammer.on('pinch', function (ev) {
    // Set the scale and render only if we have a valid pinch (inside the object)
    if (bbScope._validPinch) {
        bbScope.set('scaleX', ev.scale);
        bbScope.set('scaleY', ev.scale);
        bbScope.canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
hammer.on('pinchend', function (ev) {
    bbScope._validPinch = false;
});
hammer.on('pinchcancel', function (ev) {
    bbScope._validPinch = false;
});
hammer.on('pinchstart', function (ev) {
    // Convert mouse coordinates to canvas coordinates
    ev.clientX = ev.center.x;
    ev.clientY = ev.center.y;

    // Check if the pinch was started inside this object
    if (bbScope.canvas) {
        var p = bbScope.canvas.getPointer(ev);
        bbScope._validPinch = bbScope.containsPoint(p);
    }
    else {
        bbScope._validPinch = false;
    }
});
```